# Unable to unzip a larger file: can't open as archive - 7-zip commandline

Tags: c#, command-line, 7zip

I have a simple program using **7-Zip command line** utility to unzip a file twice. The first time the file is unzipped with a password to reveal an archive in it which now has no password. The inner archive is then extracted to reveal inner files and folders.

Here is my `SevenZip.cs` internal sealed class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _7zExeCmdLineDemo
{

    internal sealed class SevenZip
    {
        private const int ProcessTimeOut = 10000;
        private const int ProcessCheckListTimeOut = 300;
        private const string SEVENZIPEXEFILEPATH = "7-Zip/7z.exe";

        public static SevenZip Instance = new SevenZip();
        private List<FileModel> fileModels = new List<FileModel>();
        private bool startRead = false;
        private bool isrunning = false;

        public enum IfDuplicate
        {
            Overwrite,  // -aoa means to directly overwrite the existing file without prompting. Similar:
            Skip,       // -aos skip existing files will not be overwritten
            Rename,     // -aou If a file with the same file name already exists, it will automatically rename the released file
            RenameOld   // -aot If a file with the same file name already exists, it will automatically rename the existing file
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// unzip files
        /// <param> -aoa means to directly overwrite the existing file without prompting. There are similar: </ param>
        /// <param> -aos will not overwrite existing files if skipped </ param>
        /// <param> -aou If a file with the same file name already exists, it will automatically rename the released file </ param>
        /// <param> -aot If a file with the same file name already exists, it will automatically rename the existing file </ param>
        /// </ summary>
        /// <param name = "zipFilePath"> source file </ param>
        /// <param name = "destPath"> target folder </ param>
        /// <param name = "passKey"> password </ param>
        /// <param name = "duplicator"> Operation options when overwriting </ param>
        /// <returns> </ returns>
        public bool Extract(string zipFilePath, string destPath, string passKey, IfDuplicate duplicator = IfDuplicate.Overwrite)
        {
            var operation = string.Empty;
            switch (duplicator)
            {
                case IfDuplicate.Overwrite:
                    operation = " -aoa";
                    break;
                case IfDuplicate.Skip:
                    operation = " -aos";
                    break;
                case IfDuplicate.Rename:
                    operation = " -aou";
                    break;
                case IfDuplicate.RenameOld:
                    operation = " -aot";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            Process process = new Process();
            bool succeeded = false;
            System.DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = SEVENZIPEXEFILEPATH;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // Whether to use the operating system shell to start
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; // Accept input information from the calling program
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // The output information is obtained by the calling program
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; // Redirect standard error output
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // Do not display the program window

            if (passKey != null)
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"x ""{0}"" -o""{1}"" {2} -p""{3}""", zipFilePath, destPath, operation, passKey);
            else
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"x ""{0}"" -o""{1}"" {2}", zipFilePath, destPath, operation);

            process.Start(); // Start the program
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit(ProcessTimeOut); // Wait for the program to finish and exit the process

            succeeded = (startTime.AddMilliseconds(ProcessTimeOut) > DateTime.Now);
            process.Close();
            return succeeded;
        }

    }
}
```

And when using this in my program elsewhere

```
SevenZip.Instance .Extract(
    @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\SecuredArchive.zip",
    @"C:\Users\User\Documents", 
    "password",
    SevenZip.IfDuplicate.Overwrite
);

SevenZip.Instance .Extract(
    @"C:\Users\User\Documents\InnerArchive.zip", 
    @"C:\Users\User\Documents\InnerArchive", 
    "",
    SevenZip.IfDuplicate.Overwrite
);
```

Now this app works well for small archives of maybe up to 200 MB but when testing it someone generated a package  of 3GB in size and only the first extraction worked. And here is my console output:

> 7-Zip 19.00 (x86) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21
>
> Scanning the drive for archives: 1 file, 3217945253 bytes (3069 MiB)
>
> Extracting archive: C:\Users\User\Downloads\SecuredArchive.zip
>
> 7-Zip 19.00 (x86) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21
>
> Scanning the drive for archives: 1 file, 3217577691 bytes (3069 MiB)
>
> Extracting archive: C:\Users\User\Documents\InnerArchive.zip
>
> Can't open as archive: 1
>
> Files: 0
>
> Size:       0
>
> Compressed: 0

I am still learning how to use command line utilities in my c# apps for desktop and I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this because I don't know what else to fix here. The InnerArchive.zip gets locked for like 2 minutes even after I terminate the app.

Comment: There are different versions of the zip specification with optional configurations.  When I've had issues like this it was caused by somebody adding files to an existing zip file.  The added files were appended to the zip file and the tool I was using to unzip did not handle the appended file.  Using a different zip utility solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will put that into action immediately.